# What does -Dmaven.test.skip=null do?

Tags: maven

During my latest interview I was asked about the effects of the following properties set in Maven:

1. -DskipTests
2. -Dmaven.test.skip=true
3. -Dmaven.test.skip=null

I'm aware that the second point compared to the first just skips compiling the tests, but what effect has the following?

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `-Dmaven.test.skip=null` the Maven Surefire plugin attempts to coerce `null` to a `boolean` and since this cannot be done the plugin falls back to the default value for this property: `false`.

So, `-Dmaven.test.skip=null` is equivalent to `-Dmaven.test.skip=false` or, more succinctly; it's the equivalent of not specifying the `maven.test.skip` property.

Answer (score 0):

Since you basically set a system property it depends on the actual maven plugin.

The `maven.test.skip` property is honored by surefire, failsafe and the compiler plugin, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html)

So you would have to know the implementations - well... forget it.

I guess what this question really meant is what if you set a system property to `null` - would it have any effect at all?

And yes it does.

```
zarathustra@hel ~ % java -Dfancy=true -Dmaven.test.skip=null -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
    fancy = true
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
...
    maven.test.skip = null
...
```

BTW you can also write  `-DskipTests=true` which is the same as `-DskipTests` to my knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

Any value other than `true` would make the maven build behave the way as if the System Variable was not supplied or is set to `false`. So, the tests will run when the maven build is executed